# what are session id? in php are session id assined to each user or each browser

Tags: session-cookies, sessionid

i am really confused about sessions in php i doing website this is my first project and i am stuck a user logging system i cant understand how php session work are these session id unique to each user or are these unique to each browser

here is my problem

when i login in using username and password for user1 i start a new session and a unique session id is created lets say phpssesid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX so when i logout from user1 i destroy session and session id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX generated during login for user1 is deleted from temp folder 
next i login using user2 and password a new session  is again created but i get same session id i.e XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX which was generated during first login i dont understand how come to users are assigned same session id to two different users

all this while i was using google chrome to browse

but then i used firefox to login using user1 and password but this time a new session id is created i.e XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1 den i logout and again login using user2 and again session id assigned to user2 is same XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1

i dont understand all this if sesssion id is unique to each user then why is same session id is assigned to two different users on same browser

Comment: Argh. Are all your punctuation keys *kaput*?

Comment: How do you generate your session IDs?

Comment: @LinusKleen keys r woking fine but my find is not gone i have been woking 5 hr on strech to find an answer to my problem

Comment: @dgw i am using session_start(); and using phpssesid for session id

Answer (score 1):

Can't say much for PHP specifically, but HTTP by itself is *stateless* - i.e. if you make the same request, you (should) get the same response. What PHP and many other languages do is use session IDs - sometimes stored in cookies, sometimes stored in the URL.

Long story short, your Session ID should be unique to each user for each browser. For example, if Alice logs in on her home computer, then logs in on her work computer, the session IDs should be different. If Alice then logs out of her home computer and Bob logs in (same computer, same browser as Alice's first login) he should still get a different session ID - it's all done so that your framework (ie. PHP) can track 'sessions' of website use.

In your case, duplicate session IDs might be due to lingering cookies, server problems, or PHP might be legitimately reusing one ID (maybe for performance reasons). If you haven't modified much of the session code, chances are it's either the cookie issues with the browser or ID reuse.

Comment: thanks buddy your answer helpd me but can you please give me a simple demo how to generate unique session for each user on each different computer  please your help will be really appriciated.

Comment: Two people using the same browser ... this is a problem unless user A invalidates his/her session (either as a function of your application or by deleting his cookies) before user B uses the browser. If user A closes the browser (not just the tab but whole program) this problem won't arise.

Comment: thanks @dgw can you please explain me one more thing when we type javascript:void(alert(document.cookie)) we get list of cookies from that domian stored on our machine what are these utma utmz ytmc stand for

Comment: utma, utmz, etc. are for Google analytics - http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Utma,_utmb,_utmz_cookies